# Program to idifferent types of numbers

Tags: java

I am writing a program to identify prime numbers as well as other types of numbers.
How can I only read in the first number of each line?
for example if i have my text file and it contains:

1 5
2
3
6.

it should only pay attention to the first number of each line (1,2,and 3 in this case). 6. should also be ignored because it is not a "Valid input". 
How do i write code for this??

Comment: Typo. `if (isPrime = true)` is assignment, and evaluates to `true`. Use `if (isPrime == true)` or **better** `if (isPrime)`

Comment: Here is another way to read/write a file in java:
http://www.codejava.net/java-se/file-io/how-to-read-and-write-text-file-in-java

Answer (score 3):

```
if (isPrime = true)
```

i am sure you meant

```
if (isPrime == true)
```

?

which could well be written as

```
if (isPrime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct. Notice in the following code you are checking if it is divisiable by two, but the first time it is not even you go down and assign `isPrime` to true and then printing out it is prime.

```
 for (int i =2; i <= number/2;i++){
            if(number % i == 0){
                isPrime = false;
        if (isPrime = true)
```

Look at the following code, I have modified the loop so it breaks once it is divisible by a number and there is no remainder.

```
File inputFile = new File(fileName);
Scanner read = new Scanner(inputFile);
int number;

    do { 
        number = read.nextInt(); 
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for (int i =2; i <= number/2;i++) {
            if(number % i == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
           }
            if(isPrime)
                System.out.println(+ number+" "+"-"+" "+"prime"); 
         } while (number > 0);
```

Comment: Do *what*? Just dumping changed code isn't helpful; you need to explain what you have changed, as well as why.

Comment: @AndyTurner you are right, I gave a little bit of more information.

Comment: Check your code. This isn't correct (you can't close a `for` loop with a `while`)

Comment: @AndyTurner I made some changes and it tried it out now and it seems to work for me.